# Using provided CLI for a Go library

Tags: go

I would like to extract files compressed using the "siva" file format. Their library is written in Go and can be obtained using

```
go get -u gopkg.in/src-d/go-siva.v1/...
```

Apparently, they have also provided a command line interface. Given some Go package obtained using `go get`, how does one use the CLI? What am I missing here?

Here is the Github repo: https://github.com/src-d/go-siva#cli.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

For arbitrary Go source code, one can just do `go build` in the directory.

For this case, there was a sub-directory called `cmd`, and after running `go build` there, one gets a `siva` executable.